# How to use color_palette and fill_palette in ggbarplot?

Tags: ggpubr

I'm using this code `ggbarplot(cell_tidy,"label","n",fill = "groups",color = "label",position = position_dodge(),add = "mean_se",palette = c("white","royalblue4"))+theme_classic2()`

and I obtained this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nmPB.png)

I want to change only the color palette as a function of label, I have tried `color_palette` but I received this error `Error in !is.null(facet.by) | combine : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`

Thanks in advance for the help!